# How can I multiply a constant value with each line of a text file in Python?

Tags: python

I have written codes to read the lines of a txt file. I just want to multiply each line with a constant value "60". I'm not sure how to write the codes in a correct way?

```
data = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        currentPlace = line[:-1]
        data.append(currentPlace)
for i in data:
    print(i * 60)
```

Comment: You need to convert each line to a number (either `int` or `float`) before multiplying.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how to do that correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        currentPlace = line[:-1]
        data.append(currentPlace)
for i in data:
    print(float(i) * 60)
```